# How to find time spent by users on a page

Tags: analytics

Please can u help me with information how to find time spent by the users on a page on our Sharepoint.

Comment: You can log the time using javascript. you need to manage one list for log. 
You need to log start time when page load first time and End time on the closing of the  browser tab. this way you can log the time for pages in that list.

Answer (score 2):

is payable version is OK for you? By default SharePoint analytics is not very useful to analyse user activity (hits and visits only).

We have used in some our project [Piwik](https://piwik.org/sharepoint-analytics/) platform which is powerful as google as but offline.

Hope this helps,

Andrew